# Okta sign-in widget - password requirements not being displayed as bullet list

Tags: okta, okta-signin-widget

My understanding is that Okta would display the password complexity text as a bullet list instead of a comma-separated list.

Is the bullet list the default styling or it should be added manually?

Packages versions:

- `"@okta/okta-signin-widget": "5.5.3"`
- `"@okta/okta-auth-js": "4.3.0"`
- `"@okta/okta-vue": "3.0.0"`

(Sign-In Widget's CSS is being imported)

[image: Actual outcome]

[image: expected outcome]

Comment: Did you add the Sign-In Widget's CSS to your app? https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/embedded-siw/main/

Comment: Was my first instinct to see if that was being imported. Yes, I am importing it. Thank you for asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, this issue is solved by adding `showPasswordRequirementsAsHtmlList: true` to the `features` property in the config.

```js
new OktaSignIn({
    ...config,
    features: {
        showPasswordRequirementsAsHtmlList: true,
    },
});
```